# How to investigate and fix missing libraries and/or skipping incompatible library?

Tags: centos, gcc, ld

I have one secret library built for CentOS 6.5 as a package. I can't build package for CentOS 7.4, make install fails on this line:

```
$ gcc -static -O3 -Wno-long-long -funroll-loops -Wall -g -DLINUX testlib.c -o test-lib -L. -llsh -lstdc++

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

I tried to investigate this, for example:

```
$ ld -lstdc++ --verbose
...
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libstdc++.a failed
ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

I take a look at some paths and found this: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
I created symlink (tried to cheat this) but go another error:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so

$ ld -lstdc++ --verbose
...
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libstdc++.so failed                                                                                                                                                 
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libstdc++.a failed                                                                                                                                                  
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so failed                                                                                                                                                                     
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libstdc++.a failed            
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so failed                                                     
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.a failed                            
attempt to open /lib64/libstdc++.so failed                                    
attempt to open /lib64/libstdc++.a failed           
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libstdc++.a failed                                          
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so failed                                                       
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.a failed   
attempt to open /lib/libstdc++.so succeeded         
ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++                                                           
attempt to open /lib/libstdc++.a failed             
attempt to open /usr/lib/libstdc++.so succeeded                          
ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
attempt to open /usr/lib/libstdc++.a failed                                                              
ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

CentOS 6.5:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
```

CentOS 7.4:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
```

Please, help to fix this. Also, looking forward to get some advice how to investigate such issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to install:

- libstdc++-static
- glibc-static

Starting from Redhat 7/CentOS 7, static libraries was moved to an optional package. In CentOS 6 it was a part of:

- libstdc++-devel
- glibc-devel

Comment: It works, could you explain why, please?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the `devel` version of the libraries, so install:

- `libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-16.el7`
- `glibc-devel-2.17-196.el7`

Comment: no, both packages installed and exactly the same versions